# rename files in folder using C code

Tags: c

i have 3 folders each one containes different file names 
and i would like to rename files of each folder as the following example :

```
folder1                     folder 2                            folder3

image1.pnm                  image1.pnm                        image1.pnm

image2.pnm                  image2.pnm                        image2.pnm

.....                       .....                                     .....

imageN.pnm                  imageN.pnm                        imageN.pnm
```

```html
void change_all_filename_in_dir(char *dirname)
{
    char newname[] = "image";
    char extension[] = ".jpg"; 
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    int i = 0;
    
    if ((dir = opendir (dirname)) != NULL) 
    {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
        {
            rename(ent->d_name, strcat(strcat(newname, i), extension);
            i++;
        }
    closedir (dir);
    } 
    else 
    {
       printf(" folder not openend");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt at all to solve it yourself?

Comment: yes i've tried  look to my code

Comment: You need to study the fundamentals of pointers, arrays and string handling. C has no string class which magically allocates memory for you, so your strcat calls are causing complete havoc, because each strcat calls writes to the `newname` array and tries to append various things out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `rename()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
```

> Description
>
> The rename function causes the file whose name is the string pointed to by old to be
>   henceforth known by the name given by the string pointed to by new. The file named
>   old is no longer accessible by that name. If a file named by the string pointed to by new
>   exists prior to the call to the rename function, the behavior is implementation-defined.
>
> The rename function returns zero if the operation succeeds, nonzero if it fails, in
>   which case if the file existed previously it is still known by its original name.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but am i obliged to list all files of each folder ?

Comment: @maylesse Pass the file name to the file you wish to change. That's all the function does, your program has to do the rest.

Comment: can you check my code